# union two FSA's with different symbol lists

Tags: fst

I have two finite state acceptors, `a.fst` and `b.fst`. They are both unweighted, simply encoding sequences of words. Their symbol (word) lists have some overlap, but are not identical. Now I want a union of these two fst's.

I think some kind of symbol normalization/mapping should be done before calling `fstunion`. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: You'll first need to ensure they use the same alphabet -- usually just the union of the alphabets.

Comment: yeah, I can union their alphabets first, then how can I "remapping" the arcs using this new alphabet?

Comment: None of the arcs change -- they use the same symbol from the original alphabet which is still present in the new alphabet.  For the states, the easiest is to add a new start state with epsilon transitions to the start states of the original FSMs.  You now have a valid NFA, which you can convert to a DFA if you wish.

Comment: Is this process doable by calling openfst in bash? Could you share the commands?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `openfst` but given that it is a general tool for fsts I imagine it would support doing these things (and probably union directly)